# Problem with loading images from child theme CSS file with relevant path

Tags: images, child-theme, subdomains, paths

I am getting an issue with loading relevant images within CSS file from a child theme directory. I placed -

> Sites: example.com OR sub-domain.example.com

```
body{
background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/images/some-image.png);
}
```

Now the above works fine when the site is in the root folder (*or sub-domains*) but the path breaks when the site is from a sub-directory installation.

> Site: example.com/sub-folder

I tried with

```
body{
    background-image: url(../wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/images/some-image.png);
    }
```

Now it works in sub-folders but again breaks in the root or sub-domain.

How to write the correct file path which will work in both root or sub-directory site where the images will be loaded from a child theme folder (*say **images** folder*)

Comment: Where is the CSS file stored in your child theme?

Comment: Simply try `background:url(images/some-image.png)` if css file and image folder in same folder. Else use `../` to specify location. No need to start url with `wp-content`.

Comment: in the root of the theme directory. themes/child-theme-name/style.css

Comment: To be clear, it would be great if you can update your question with URLs to both main site and sub folder site pages where images look broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for the `wp-content/themes` path - both themes sit in the same directory, so you can just traverse up one and then back down to child theme:

```
background-image: url(../child-theme-name/images/some-image.png);
```

**Update:** Regarding your answer to "where is the CSS file stored", you inferred that the stylesheet resides in the child theme folder - in which case you are *massively* overcomplicating things and can just use (as @Rishabh suggested):

```
background-image: url(images/some-image.png);
```

Relative paths in a stylesheet are **relative to the stylesheet itself** - not the document, the parent theme, or anything else for that matter.